# Django: The HTML template fails to be converted to PDF

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, pdf-generation

I am fairly new to Django and also JS/Jquery.

I am trying to generate a pdf view of my HTML template, upon clicking the "Approve" Button. I have also written a js/jquery script within the same template to generatea pdf and instead I'm redirected to my homepage; just as I have defined it to do so in the corresponding view method. 
I'm wondering now why it does not run the js/jquery script and keeps referring to my view method and also what can I do to make it go through the script and convert the page to PDF and downloads it for the user, after hitting "Approve" Button.

Many thanks for your smart comments !

## My Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/quote_letter_est.css' %}">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"> 
</script>

<title>Estimate Quote Letter</title>
<script>
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#Approve').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
</script>
</head>
<div id="content">
<body  bgcolor="#ffffff" border="1">
    <form action="http://{{host}}:{{port}}/label/approve001" method="Get">
    {%csrf_token%}
        {% block content %}
            {% if cust_data %}
              {% for row in cust_data %}
                  <table id = "print-friendly" class="print-friendly" style="width:80%; cellspacing:0;">
                        <td colspan="8" align="left" valign="top" >{{ row.contact_fname }}&nbsp;{{ row.contact_lname }}<br>We trust that the following estimate meets with your approval and we look forward to working with you.<br><br>
                        </td>
                        <th colspan="2" align="left" style="width:300px; height:25px; font-size:14px;">
                        <p>TO: <br>{{ row.customer }} <br>{{row.add_line1}}, 
                           {{row.add_line2}} <br>{{ row.city}}, {{ 
                            row.province}}{{ row.postal_code}} 
                            <br>ATTN:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ row.contact_lname }} 
                            <br>Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ row.phone }} 
                            <br>Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ row.email }}</th> </p> 

                        <th></th><th align="left" style="width:300px; 
                        height:25px; font-size:14px;">QUOTATION#:&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                        {{ quotation_number }}<br>Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ 
                         current_date}}<br><br>Sales Person:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ 
                         row.sales_person }}<br>CSR:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{row.csr}} 
                         <br>Estimator:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{estimater}}
                       </th>
                       <input type="hidden"  name="Description" id="Description"     value={{quote_description}}>
                       <input type="hidden"  name="sales_person" id="sales_person"     value={{sales_person}}>
                       <input type="hidden"  name="csr_name" id="csr_name"     value={{csr_name}}>
                       <input type="hidden"  name="estimater" id="estimater"     value={{estimater}}>
                       <input type="hidden"  name="contact_lname" id="contact_lname"     value={{row.contact_lname}}>
                       <input type="hidden"  name="contact_fname" id="contact_fname"     value={{row.contact_fname}}>
                       <input type="hidden"  id="quotation_id" name="quotation_id" value={{ quotation_number }}>
                       <input type="hidden" name="deal_id" value={{ deal_id }}>
              </table>
              <button class="myButton" id="Approve" type="submit" name="approve001" formaction="approve001/" value=approve001>Approve</button>

              <input type="button" class ="myButton" name="Revise_All" 
               onclick="window.location.href='http://{{host}}: 
               {port}}/label/generate_quotation_letter001/letter_quotation/? 
               id='+ quotation_id.value + '&deal_id=' + deal_id.value "  
               value="Revise" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## and this my view method (Note the request.GET values are being fetched from database and are dealt with in another method and there is no problem there).

```
class approve(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        print ("Step 1 121get")
        part = request.GET['quotation_id']
        try:
            req_id = request.GET['quotation_id']
        except:
            req_id = ""
        try:
           verb = request.GET['approve001']
        except:
            verb = ""

        if verb == "decline001": #""decline":
            print ("decline data............")
        try:
            self.UpdateStatusRequest(req_id, "Request-Declined")
        except:
            quotation_id = ""

    elif verb == "approve001": #""approved":
        print ("approve data............")
        try:
            self.UpdateStatusRequest(req_id, "Request-Approved")
        except:
            quotation_id = ""
    return redirect('/')

def UpdateStatusRequest(self, req_id, status_state):
    print("pppppppppp", req_id, status_state)
    query = "update label_newquote set status=" + "'" + status_state + "' " + " WHERE id = " + str(req_id) + ";"
    print (query)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)

def post(self, request):
    print("Step 1 post")
    try:
        submit = request.POST.get('submit')
    except:
        submit = ""
    try:
        decline = request.POST.get('decline')
    except:
        decline = ""
    print(submit)
    print(decline)

    return redirect('generate_quotation_letter001/letter_quotation/')
```

and just in case, this is my url:

`url(r'^generate_quotation_letter/perform_generate_quotation_letter/letter_quotation/LetterTwoQuotation/approve001/$', views_pdf.approve.as_view(), name="approve"),`

Comment: preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your js in a function and return the function on submission of the form.

Do something like this.

```
<script>
function pdfdownload(){
var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#Approve').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
return false;
}
</script>
```

and for the form

```
<form action="your_url" onsubmit="return pdfdownload()"> // your form
```

Without this call, the submit button submits whatever form it is in to the url mentioned in action of the form without executing your js.

Note that this does not submit your form after executing your js.If you want the form to be submitted to the url given in action after js execution, just change "return false" to "return true" in your function.

Comment: May God Bless You ! Thank you !